# Java string and regex matching

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to search a string(formed by concatenation of string and a regex) in another string.If the 1st string is present in the second string then i want to get the starting and ending addresses of matched phrase.
For in the following code I want to search "baby accessories India" in "baby_NN accessories_NNS India_NNP is_VBZ an_DT online_JJ shopping_NN portal_NN " and want to get "baby_NN accessories_NNS India_NNP" as result.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexMatching {


public static void main(String aaa[])throws IOException
{

        String line="baby accessories India";
        String []str=line.split("\\ ");

        String temp="";

        int i,j;
        j=0;

        String regEx1 = "([A-Z]+)[$]?";

        for(i=0;i<str.length;i++)
            temp=temp+str[i]+"_"+regEx1+" ";


        String para2="baby_NN accessories_NNS India_NNP is_VBZ an_DT online_JJ shopping_NN portal_NN ";
        Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile(temp);
        Matcher matcher1 = pattern1.matcher(para2);

        if (para2.matches(temp)) {
            i = matcher1.start();
            j = matcher1.end();
            String temp1=para2.substring(i,j);
            System.out.println(temp1);

        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }

}
}
```

Comment: So, what have you tried? What is the outcome of your code? Is it `Error` or is it something else? The code you posted won't even compile.

Comment: @Stephan:There was a minor error i had used matcher instead of matcher1..Now it is correct..:)..The output is **Error**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with [Matcher#find()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29)

```
if (matcher1.find())
```

instead of [String#matches()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) that matches for whole string not just part of it.

```
if (para2.matches(temp))
```

output:

```
baby_NN accessories_NNS India_NNP
```

---

One more changes

```
if (matcher1.find()) {
    i = matcher1.start();
    j = matcher1.end();
    String temp1 = para2.substring(i, j-1); // Use (j-1) to skip last space character
    System.out.println(temp1);
}
```

Comment: And also use `Pattern.quote()` to escape any special characters in the input string.

Comment: Yes you are right all the characters that are already part of regex pattern must be escaped if trying to match these special characters.